# EF odd nullreferenceException with the same code already used and working

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

Sorry to bother you on this, but I'm a little confused.
I have this code in a sub called in Page_Load

```
Dim db As dbVulcanoEntities
Dim intervento As Interventi
Dim idint As Integer
idint = Request.QueryString("idint")
intervento = db.Interventi.Where(Function(i) i.IDInt = idint).Single
```

It fails on last line (in debug I see that idint has value) and if I query the db I get 1 record.
Odd thing is that I used this exact same code in another page of the same project (more than once,actually) and it works with no problem...
I can't understand why it's not working here... hints!? Thank you

EDIT:
I tried to add a condition like this

```
 If db.Interventi.Any(Function(i) i.IDInt = idint) Then
```

but it doesn't even pass it, so I guess it doesn't like the "i.IDInt = idint" part for some reason.

Comment: It return a number, idint is an integer field of the interventi table, in this case it is passed from one page to another through querystring and in debug I can see its value. Please see the EDIT above, also I tried to use convert.toint32 on querystring but it fails anyway

Comment: You need to declare `db as new dbVulcanoEntities`. Also, consider implementing this in a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: _"with the same code already used and working"_ I strongly doubt that ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter a part from the missing "new" the rest was copy-pasted ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted will, indeed, produce a `NullReferenceException` as you are never assigning a value to the `db` local variable, so I am expecting it to be `Nothing`.

Comment: I forgot the NEW tag! O_o as in Dim db As new dbVulcanoEntities. Thank you for pointing it out